# Fire event on pivot table laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

There are two `Product` and `Warehouse` models that have many to many relation ship with an extra `stock` field that specify  stock of a product in a warehouse.

`Product` Model :

```
public function warehouses()
{
    return
        $this->belongsToMany(Warehouse::class, 'product_warehouse', 'product_id', 'warehouse_id')
            ->withPivot('stock')
            ->withTimestamps();
}
```

And `Warehouse` Model :

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_warehouse', 'warehouse_id', 'product_id')->withPivot('stock')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

User can do some operations like **stock correction** or **transfer products** from one warehouse to another one. and in each of them I increase or decrease `stock` column of row that relates that product and warehouse.

Now I want to delete whole row of pivot table if stock is equal 0.

How Can I do that ?

Comment: [Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). Take a look at that section (`extends Pivot`). I don't think you need to change your existing code, just create a `model` for the `pivot` table and query it directly. `ProductWherehouse::where('stock', 0)->delete()`.

Comment: But when I call `ProductWherehouse::where('stock', 0)->delete()`? Of course I want to do this automatically

Comment: so where are you actually doing the increasing and decreasing, seems like the place to start